# Adjective + verb ing

Tags: grammar

I have a sentence:

She's very busy working three jobs.

Is that present continuous? it confuses me that there is a verb in ing after an adjective

Or is a gerund?

Thanks.

Comment: Asked before on ELL, but no adequate answer.

Comment: Here, the sentence is "She's very busy." and the remaining tells 'how'.

Answer (score 1):

'Working' in 'She's busy working [three jobs]' is a complement of the adjective 'busy', not a type of second predicate. In The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (Huddleston & Pullum; 2002) (p 1259):

> **Gerund-participial complements**
>
> The adjectives **busy** and **worth**/**worthwhile** license
>   complements of this form:
>
> *She was busy preparing her report.*
>
> *These objections aren't worth bothering about.*
>
> *It isn't worth taking the matter any further.*

CGEL gives further analysis of the 'worth / worthwhile' examples.

..........

Contrast 'She's very tired, [what with] working such long hours'

and 'She's very busy, [what with] doing three jobs'

which use adjuncts, here (ignoring the *what with*'s) participial clauses of reason (or expansion perhaps, in the latter example).

Comment: Why is that book so expensive?   I got the Cambridge grammar of Classical Greek for about $30!

Comment: Click [here](http://93.174.95.29/main/2297000/69b32a592db2ee72fcbba60fb375ae40/Rodney%20Huddleston_%20Geoffrey%20K.%20Pullum%20-%20The%20Cambridge%20Grammar%20of%20the%20English%20Language-Cambridge%20University%20Press%20%282002%29.pdf)